# How to get MAC and IP's of devices on external networks with python

Tags: python, networking, packets, sniffing

I have been working with packets, in doing so I have been making some sniffing programs, in which pick up packets that are broadcasted (one of which is below). I wanted to add to my program a way to tell me the device MAC and (if possible) Their IP addresses (internal for that network) on external networks that were sniffed (Scan a separate network). I know that the autoconnect option on devices allows you to view a devices IP/MAC and the network in which they have connected to in the past (Due to them broadcasting it), however, that, as far as I know, only works when they are on your network. If there is any way I could do this, that would be great (Like airodump-ng) Here is the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import scapy
import os
import optparse
import sys
import socket
from scapy.all import *
import platform
os_type = platform.system()
if(os_type != "Linux"):
    print("[-] Error. Made for Linux.")
    try:
            exit(0)
    except:
        sys.exit(1)
class c:
    r = '\033[0;31m'
    g = '\033[0;32n'
    o = '\033[0;33m'
    b = '\033[0;94m'
    p = '\033[0;35m'
    d = '\033[0;00m'
    w = '\033[0;54m'
class ssid_fingerprint:
    w_ssid = 'Dot11'
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", action="store", dest="inter", help="Interface Protocal", default="no_interface")
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
error = c.w+'['+c.r+'-'+c.w+'] '
if(options.inter=="no_interface"):
    print(error+'You must supply a interface')
    try:
        exit(0)
    except:
        sys.exit(1)
#elif('mon' not in str(options.inter)):
#   print(error+'You must use a monitor interface')
#   try:
#       exit(0)
#   except:
#       sys.exit(1)
ssid_captures = []
#subprocess.Popen(['ifconfig '+options.inter+' down ; ifconfig '+options.inter+' promisc ; ifconfig '+options.inter+' up'], shell=True)
while True:
    try:
        ssid_packet = sniff(iface=options.inter, count = 1)
        for pck in ssid_packet:
            if(pck.haslayer(Dot11)):
                try:
                    ssid_layer = pck.getlayer(Dot11)
                    ssid_name = ssid_layer.info
                    ssid_mac = ssid_layer.addr2
                    ssid_string = str(ssid_name)+':'+str(ssid_mac)
                    if(ssid_string not in ssid_captures):
                        ssid_captures.append(str(ssid_name)+':'+str(ssid_mac))
                    print('[*] SSID: {} | SSID MAC:     {}').format(ssid_name, ssid_mac)
                except:
                    pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Captured SSID's:"),
        print(ssid_captures)
        try:
            exit(0)
        except:
            sys.exit(1)
#   except OSError:
#       subprocess.Popen(['ifconfig '+options.inter+' down ; ifconfig '+options.inter+' promisc ; ifconfig '+options.inter+' up'], shell=True)
#   except socket.error:
#       pass
    except:
        raise
```

Comment: MAC addresses are only valid or seen on the LAN where the hosts with those MAC addresses are connected. Routers strip off the frame headers from packets and create new frames for the next interface through which a packet must pass, thereby losing any of the original layer-2 addressing. Also, not all layer-2 protocols use MAC addresses, only the IEEE LAN protocols do, and some of those use 48-bit MAC addresses, while others use 64-bit MAC addresses. Protocols like PPP don't use any addressing, while protocols like ATM or frame relay use something else entirely.

Comment: @RonMaupin Is there a way I could intercept these frames without going on their network, also if the layer 2 addressing is lost, how is airodump-ng able to capture the MACs on external networks?

Comment: The frames do not leave the LAN. As I explained, a router will strip the frames off the packets. Router route packets by the layer-3 address, so they dump the layer-2 information, and they must make new layer-2 frames for the network of the next interface to which it sends the packets. This is Routing 101.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point. I made no assumptions about your level of knowledge, I merely pointed out that this is basic routing knowledge. You can certainly research this, but from the [help/on-topic]: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"